# Unable to locate any html element in an iFrame with Selenium IDE

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, xpath, selenium-ide

I have to make a navigation script with Selenium IDE in an internal web application of my company.
The problem is that I need to catch any element on a page that has iFrame and that iFrame has everything in the page (the main body tag, div tags, the form, JS scripts, etc)
My Selenium script works well until:

```
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
  <td>open</td>
  <td>{my URL}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//ul[@id='any ID']/li/a/span</td>
 <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>//html/body/iframe</td>
 <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>selectFrame</td>
 <td>myFrameID</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

And when I try to insert any other command as 'assertElementPresent', 'verifyElementPresent', 'assertText', etc, my script fails because Selenium doesn´t find the locator elements. I'm using Selenium IDE 2.9.0 and Firefox as browser.

Does anybody know how to do it?? I need help as soon as possible.

Comment: You may need to read up on using frames, you can do that here: http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the xpath by locating it using xpath extension of firebug. that can give you the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helping, I could solve my doubt about iFrames with Selenium IDE by myself, and I have just made some complex scripts without problems.

Now I have another doubt that I would like to ask you guys:

I have in a JSP page a form and inside this form, when I select an option in a combo another four combos are shown. In my Selenium script I have recorded the Select command when I select in the first combo, and after the other combos have appeared, I have recorded a Click command in another button.
But when I execute the script, the Click command is executed before the Select commands in the four combos mentioned above.

Why the **Click** command is executed before the **Select** command when I play my script??